# How to resume Cordova iOS app

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using iOS cordova-2.1.0,jqueryMobile and html5.I have added feature of phone call inside the app,when I click on 'Phone Call' link it prompts me to call or cancel.If I choose cancel button then app resumes,but if I choose call then after ending call app does not resumes its restarts.I have added UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend in appName.plist because I want to exit the app when it goes into background after pressing the home button.

Comment: Mr.snehad UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend remove this key from  appName.plist your application will not restart when you press call button

Comment: but i want to exit app when we press home button

Comment: Ok snehad . when you make call from inside the app same functionality as pressing home button . So cannot be changed

Comment: Is there any alternative solution

Comment: Please reply me I have wasted my day :(

Comment: i think there is no  way , in javascript we can handle resume , but you set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend which apple , both are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the application goes to background when a call is triggered. if the application does not support suspend/resume feature just like yours "`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`", it is same as pressing HOME button for the application and hence the application does not resume.

either you have to remove this key and let the application resume or there is no other choice

Comment: Ok,thanks samfisher.But is there any other way to exit app except "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" and I am using smsComposer plugin in that whether you send SMS or cancel it,app always resumes.

Comment: Is there any way to capture the state of app before phone call and after the call end we could start the app from that state only???